# How to divide a dataset according to a value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, object-slicing

I have a pandas data frame with a column that represents dates as:

```
Name: ts_placed, Length: 13631, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

It looks like this ( it was recoded using week as time unit):

```
0     42
1     44
2     44
3     41
4     43
5     45
6     46
...
```

What I want to do is to create a new pandas data frame for each week. In other words, I should obtain a data frame that contains only elements that have the value 42 in the column 'ts_placed' a data frame that contains only elements that have the value 43 in the column 'ts_placed' and so on.

Comment: Why do you need this? Why not just `groupby` on `ts_placed` and access the individual groups?

Comment: EdChum I need to divide them further and compute different operation on them. it would be more practical to treat them as different data frames

Comment: But surely managing lots of dfs is more painful than just accessing the individual weeks as groups and performing operations on them?

Comment: they are not too many and despite this i wanted to learn how to do it in general. Let's say you have only true and false in a column and you want to divide the dataframe in 2 according to this

Comment: I agree with EdChum totally, as long as they share the column/index I really don't see the real benefits separating them into individual dataframes. In latter case True/False, a simple masking will just do fine

Comment: Basically the general form would be `df_week_x = df[df['ts_placed'] == x]` where x would be your week number, the boolean condition will return a boolean series that masks the df